# Argument not specified for parameter when saving a screenshot of the form

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save a screenshot of the form as a `.png file` by clicking a button on the screen, the code that I'm using to screenshot the form is this:

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height))
    End Using
    Return tmpImg
End Function
```

and then calling this function in the `buttons_click` code

```
Private Sub SaveBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBox.Click
    Call TakeScreenShot()
End Sub
```

Gives the error:

> Error  1  Argument not specified for parameter 's' of 'Public Function Screenshot(s As System.Windows.Forms.Control) As System.Drawing.Bitmap'."

```
Private Sub SaveBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBox.Click
    Call TakeScreenShot(Control)
End Sub
```

Then gives error:

> Name 'Control' is not declared.

Comment: The parameter _sender_ received in the SaveBox_Click handler is a Control. You just need to cast it to a Control type and pass it to your ScreenShot method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't take a screenshot of the form, it takes a screenshot of the entire screeen. To take a screenshot of a form, you'll need this code instead, and to use it, see the sub below. The parameter should be the name of the form you want to take a screenshot of. In this case, I merely referred to `Me` as the main form window

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Control.DrawToBitmap(tmpImg, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control.Width, Control.Height))
    Return tmpImg
End Function

Private Sub Button99_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button99.Click
    Dim bmp As Bitmap
    bmp = TakeScreenShot(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a technical correction: His current code cannot take a screenshot of whatever's behind the form because the form will always be included in the screenshot (the form is located on the screen, `g.CopyFromScreen()` copies the pixels **as you see them** from the specified area of the screen, which will always be where the form is located). Infact there is no clean, simple way to take a screenshot behind a window, only dirty workarounds.